# MySQL specify the result of the condition in the field

Tags: mysql

I want to add field in my result table, which will be `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the condition.

First table:

```
A {
   AId,
   Name
}
```

Second table:

```
B {
   BId,
   AId1,
   AId2
}
```

I want to get result where will be:

```
Result {
   AId,
   Name,
   SomeCondition
}
```

Where SomeCondition is `TRUE` if there are `ANY` items in `B` `(A.id == AId1 OR A.id == AId2)`

I imagine this like:

```
SELECT 
Id,
Name,
ANY (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.AId = B.AId1 OR A.AId = B.AId2) AS SomeCondition
FROM A;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
Id,
Name,
CASE WHEN 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE A.AId = B.AId1 OR A.AId = B.AId2) > 0 THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END AS SomeCondition
FROM A;
```

You can use 1 and 0 to represent TRUE/FALSE, or use the string literals if you wish.